# Find self-adjoint of $P=|a \rangle \langle b |$

Tags: operator-theory, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, adjoint-operators

Let $P$ be an operator s.a. $P=|a \rangle \langle b |$ and $P|f \rangle = \langle b | f \rangle | a \rangle   $.
Find the self-adjoint and the $P^2$ operator.

**My attempt:**
We know to find the self adjoint operator:
$$ \langle g | P | f \rangle = \langle P^{\dagger}g|f \rangle \Leftrightarrow \int_{a}^{b} \langle g^{*} |a \rangle\langle b |f \rangle dx =  \int_{a}^{b} P^{\dagger} g^{*} f dx $$
And from here, i can't find anything.

Comment: This is called an "adjoint", not a "self-adjoint".

Comment: $P^\dagger = (|a\rangle\langle b|)^\dagger = \langle b|^\dagger|a\rangle^\dagger = |b\rangle\langle a|$ and $P^2 = |a\rangle\langle b|a\rangle\langle b| = \langle b|a\rangle P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

- "self-adjoint" is an adjective, that indicates that something is equal to its adjoint. The noun is "adjoint".
- The equalities $P=|a\rangle\langle b|$ and $P|f\rangle=\langle b|f\rangle\,|a\rangle$ (for every $f$) say exactly the same.
- The bra-ket notation is pretty bad to deal with adjoints. The adjoint of $P$ is operator $P^\dagger$ such that $$\langle P^\dagger g,f\rangle=\langle g,Pf\rangle$$ for all $f,g$.
- Now you can calculate (and for the first part, the bra-ket notation is good, tough it can hide understanding):
  $$
  \langle P^\dagger g,f\rangle=\langle g,Pf\rangle=\langle g|a\rangle\langle b|f\rangle.
  $$
  In my view, this is better understood by treating the inner product properly:
  $$
  \langle P^\dagger g,f\rangle=\langle g,Pf\rangle=\langle g,(\langle b|f\rangle)a\rangle=\langle b|f\rangle\,\langle g|a\rangle=\langle\overline{\langle g|a\rangle}\,b|f\rangle
  =\langle \,\langle a|g\rangle\,b|f\rangle=\langle |b\rangle\langle a|g\big|f\rangle.
  $$
  AS this holds for all $f,g$,
  $$
  P^\dagger=|b\rangle\langle a|.
  $$
- The whole thing has nothing to do with integrals, and operators of the form $P=|a\rangle\langle b|$ can be defined for $a,b$ in any Hilbert space. It doesn't have to be space of functions, and even then the inner product doesn't have to be defined by an integral.